# Custom Typefaces currupted

Tags: android, android-view, typeface, android-typeface

I have implemented `TypefaceHelper` to cache typefaces:

```
public class TypefaceHelper {

  private static final Hashtable<String, Typeface> FONT_CACHE = new Hashtable<>();

  private static Typeface get(String name) {
     synchronized (FONT_CACHE) {
        if (!FONT_CACHE.containsKey(name)) {
            FONT_CACHE.put(name, Typeface.createFromAsset(App.getContext().getAssets(), name));
        }

        return FONT_CACHE.get(name);
     }
  }

  public static Typeface getTypeFace(MyTypeFace typeface) {
     switch (typeface) {
        default:
        case ROBOTO_REGULAR:
            return get("fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
        case ROBOTO_BOLD:
            return get("fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf");
        case ROBOTO_LIGHT:
            return get("fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
     }
  }

  public enum MyTypeFace {
    ROBOTO_BOLD,
    ROBOTO_LIGHT,
    ROBOTO_REGULAR
  }
```

}

Unfortunately, I'm now facing very strange issue. All my texts aren't sometimes (randomly) rendered correctly. It looks like this:

[image: Corrupted texts]

Thanks in advance.